# MVC3 Prep inputs after validation but before submission?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form that has a section with a dynamic number of inputs, depending on the options the user has chosen.  When the configuration posts back to the server, I want to concatenate the different values of that section into an xml string and store them in the database as one value.  The possible combinations of fields are finite; each of the three possibilities is built as a partial view that I include on load, and reload via ajax if the dropdown specifying the type of config changes.

Each partial view is typed, and has validation properties associated with it.

Here's what I want to do:  Upon the submit button being clicked, I want validation to run against all fields, but before actually submitting the form, I want to invoke a script to build the xml string and store it in a hidden input.

How do I "inject" a step between the validation and submission without having to do a bunch of custom work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it matter that it be done after validation?  Just hook your submit button clicked event, then call submit.  So it does a little work if the form isn't valid.  Not a huge deal really.

Comment: ?? Won't hooking into the submit event directly potentially circumvent validation?  I don't want anything posting to the server until and unless all validates correctly.

Comment: @Jeremy - No, don't hook the submit event.  You hook your submit button, then call the forms submit after you have done your work.  If the form fails validation, it won't submit.

Comment: How about non-js scenarios? Rest service, etc. There are plenty of events to hook into, I'm mobile, but will try to update again when I can.

Comment: I ended up doing this.  I changed the button from a submit type to a button type, grabbed the click event, built the input I wanted, then submitted.